# How to iterate with the get() function in R

Tags: r, loops, get

I have a few data frames that have the names `df_JANUARY 2020`, `df_FEBRUARY 2020` etc. (I know spaces are an ill practice in variable assignment, but it has to do with a sql query). And would like to build a function to iterate through the months of these data frames. The purpose of this is have the function (not written below) clean each df the same way.

```
date <- c("JANUARY 2020", "FEBRUARY 2020") 

x <- function(date) {
     y <- get(paste0("df_", date))
} 

for(i in seq_along(date)) {
  z <- date[i]
  assign(paste0("dfclean_", date[i]), x(z))
}
```

The problem being that when I use the get() function it's pushing the whole list through rather than one element at a time. Is there away to avoid this problem with this methodology or is there a better way to approach this problem? Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the `matrix` to `data.frame` and then use `$` as `matrix` columns are extracted with `[`

```
 x <- function(daten) {
      y <- as.data.frame(get(paste0("df_", daten)))
      y[grep("Enterprise", y$AcctType), ]

   } 


for(i in seq_along(date)) {
   z <- date[i]
     assign(paste0("dfclean_", date[i]), x(z))
  }
```

---

We can also use `mget`

```
lst1 <- mget(paste0("df_", date))
lst1 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) subset(as.data.frame(x), 
              grepl("Enterprise",AcctType)))
names(lst1) <- sub("_", "clean_", names(lst1))
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: @Amelia can you explain a bit more

Comment: I think my problem is a little more complex than I thought.


x <- function(daten) {
    y <- get(paste0("df_", daten))
    z <- y[grep("Enterprise", y$AcctType), ]
    return(z)
}

I'm getting the error Error in y$AcctType : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I'm sorry I'm having a weird problem with commenting. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Amelia Could you please add more details.

Comment: @Amelia I think you need `y[, "AcctType"]` if it is a matrix because the `$` won't work with matrix.  `data(mtcars); m1 <- as.matrix(mtcars); m1$mpg` and now use `m1[, "mpg"]`

Comment: Ideally I want keep it as a data frame, is that possible?

Comment: @Amelia Yes, in your function you may need `y <- as.data.frame(get(paste0("df_", daten)))` and then the next line should work

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't ask for this, but how about just rename all of the dataframes with `_` instead of space?

The first line assigns all of the objects in the global environment with `df` in the name to be elements of a list named `mydfs`.

The second line replaces space with `_` in the names.

The third line assigns all of the list elements into the global environment.

```
mydfs <- mget(ls(pattern = "df"), globalenv())
names(mydfs) <- gsub(" ","_",names(mydfs))
list2env(mydfs, env = globalenv())
```

Or, option two, you could just use `lapply` on `mydfs`.